# Difference between AD DS and AD LDS User object

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008, ldap

I know the major difference between the AD DS and AD LDS but if i create a user in the ad ds server it shows it in the AD LDS too so what is difference between the AD DS User object and AD LDS User object.

Ps: I am really new to the windows server and ad ds so kindly explain it in detail That will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

AD DS can authenticate domain security principals to provide access to applications and Web Services, whereas AD LDS can be used for Web authentication but does not support domain security principals